# Power Automate HTTP action with internal server error failing to route the flow to the "Run after failed" action

Tags: http, power-automate

In Power Automate I have purposefully given a wrong password for the HTTP action, and I have configured a parallel branch which is configured to run if the HTTP action is failed/skipped/timed out. The retry policy has changed from "Default" to "None". In this configuration, I'm getting an internal server error, but the flow is not routing to the "Run after failed action".[image: Power Automate flow screenshot]